# hibernate 4.3.5 with classmate on glassfish 4 typeresolver error

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish, classmate

I recently updated an app i'm working on from glassfish 3.1.2 to glassfish 4.0, and in the process updated my hibernate to 4.3.5.

after getting everything together, when i try to actually deploy my app and hit the front page, on the first database requests, i get errors like this:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Jersey Web Application]: Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver.resolve(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;[Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Lcom/fasterxml/classmate/ResolvedType;
```

I looked this error up on google and am unable to find anyone with a similar problem, and i'm wondering if i am doing something wrong with my annotations?   I am using entity manager, and persistence methods to annotate Entity beans as my method of db access, and it was working fine before the upgrade.   Unfortunatey, the documentation for fasterxml.classmate seems to have moved or disappeared, and i don't know if there is something i'm supposed to be doing to enable it to work properly.  Alternately, there may be something i need to change in the way things are set up that i'm unaware of....

Any help appreciated....has anyone seen something like this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issue. In my case solution was to add classmate-1.0.0.jar to classpath. Previously I had version 0.5.3 and it was not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

so apparently i had included hibernate's validator jar in my project, and although i had removed it, doing "clean" in eclipse failed to remove the jar from the deployed directory.   As i had not set up validation in any way, when i removed the jar, it caused me to stop getting this error.   I'm not sure how great of a solution that may be for anyone else, but it solved my problem, so i'm including the answer here.